# UIviewController view stuck while switching between different tabs quickly using UItabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a App in which I am using both `UINavigationController` and `UItabbarController`, issue I am facing is when I switch between different tabs quickly `UIViewcontrollers` views stucks but tabbar is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: Would be better you could provide some gif of issue.

Comment: Please check this video, I have made video of this issue 

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1e9rki31s2fwb5/Issue.mov?dl=0)

Comment: it seems to ba a bug you need to check it inside your thirdtab's view controller

Comment: Do you think it's because of some memory leakage or disturbance of UIviewControllers stack ?